# Virtualbox sometimes unable to connect to router

Tags: networking, router, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have virtualbox installed on my mac (El Capitan) and my box has windows 8 on it. It used to work fine with adapter set to bridged, but now (most of the time) it's unable to get an ip from my router and so just has some default ip and so I'm unable to access the internet. Every so often it works, usually by me restarting my mac and then firing up virtualbox again, but 9/10 times this doesn't solve the issue.

I've tried the other vm's I have on vb too and they have the same issue, so it's not just this windows vm.

Comment: Use a NATted vNIC.

Comment: Seems to be the same on parallels too :/ ... I can't use a NAT I need to access the vm from outside.

Comment: you can access a NATted VirtualBox VM from outside. Just set up port forwarding in VirtualBox. example for ssh: port forward port 2222 (or whatever) on your public IP to your host IP and port 2222 (or any else, keep it above 1024) and use VirtualBox forwarding from port 2222 to your NATted VMs IP port 22.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that although my vm was unable to successfully get an ip from my routers dhcp server, I was still able to manually set its ip, gateway etc.
[How to manually set windows ip](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/15089/windows-change-tcp-ip-settings#1TC=windows-7). This solved the issue, and saved me from having to set the network adapter to NAT and go through the trouble of port forwarding.